# resequence out of order messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, message

What is the best C++ data structure and stl routines that I can use for resequencing messages that occur out of order?  I have a stream of messages that I need to process. Often it is better to farm the messages off to multiple threads for processing.  But once they are processed I need to put them back into the original order so that I can send them out.  I was thinking of a std::vector and to have a int to hold what the first index is for the vector.  I have no issues numbering the messages from 1->n before I send them off to the threads for processing so I have a gapless sequence of numbers to use for resequencing them.

Comment: If you have proper synchronization you should just check your complexity requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best container to use for this purpose is a std::priority_queue.